# Как сослаться на библиотеку расширения .a в проекте Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Есть проект [libjson-rpc-cpp](https://github.com/cinemast/libjson-rpc-cpp) .
Готовый фреймворк для Windows содержит в себе библиотеки расширения ".a" . Как написано, они тестили проект на Windows 7 при помощи MinGW32.

Каким образом мне можно подключить эти библиотеки к с++ проекту в VS? 
Стандартными способами, которыми я подключаю библиотеки расширения .lib эти библиотеки (.a) не подключаются. То есть VS ругается на неразрешённый внешний символ.

```
Ошибка  9   error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ
"public: __thiscall jsonrpc::HttpClient::HttpClient(class
std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class
std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0HttpClient@jsonrpc@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) 
в функции _wmain    E:\Projects\A1CF service projects\A1CF service
```

У меня такое уже было. Решил вопрос, добавив исходники нужные в проект.

В итоге, вопросы:

1. Эти библиотеки (.a) реально использовать не на Linux?
2. Эти библиотеки (.a) собраны при помощи MinGW?
3. Каким образом их можно использовать в проекте  VC++? Может быть можно конвертировать или скомпилировать заново, чтобы сгенерировались .lib файлы?

На Ubuntu я выкачал из git проект, собрал его. Думаю, можно изменить параметры CmakeLists.txt, чтобы генерировались .lib файлы. 
Но мб можно без этого использовать файлы .a расширения сразу в VC++ проекте?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовать библиотеки C++, которые собраны другим компилятором, в общем случае, нельзя. У разных компиляторов могут быть разные имена(name mangling) и т.п. Поэтому нельзя даже использовать библиотеку, которая была собрана в другой версии MSVC. Про MinGW я вообще молчу.

Выход здесь это собрать библиотеку самостоятельно. Для этого нужно запустить cmake с нужным генератором. Список всех генераторов можно получить, запустив `cmake` без параметров в консоли.

Вот так, к примеру, как будет выглядеть генерация solution для MSVC2013 x64:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 Win64"
```

Answer (score 3):

Статическая библиотека .a, может быть использована только с MinGW32, т.к. создана им. Для использования Visual Studio вам необходимо собрать проект в Visual Studio. Также если у вас есть динамическая библиотека (dll) этого проекта вы можете создать из неё lib файл (инструкция: http://unick-soft.ru/article.php?id=56)